# Format numbers in Django with Intcomma

Tags: django, format

I am having issues trying to use |intcomma to format a number.

Let's say I multiply the values a and b which adds up to 1000000 by using:

```
<h2>{% widthratio item.a 1 item.b %}</h2>
```

All examples out there use intcomma with only one value:

```
<h2>{{ item.a|intcomma }}</h2>
```

So my question is, how do you combine widthratio with intcomma in order to get the multiplied number formatted as 1,000,000.
Example below which do not work:

```
<h2>{% widthratio value|intcomma 1 value|intcomma %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`widthratio`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio) accepts an argument `as <variable>`, this stores the result of the calculation in a variable that can then be used in your template

```
{% widthratio item.a 1 item.b as foo %}
<h2>{{ foo|intcomma }}</h2>
```